# Microsoft Azureのx5cのKeyをCA証明書(pem)に変換したい

Tags: azure, openssl

プログラム系でない質問の旨、失礼いたします。

Azureの `login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys` のx5cのkeyを、
CA証明書に変換したいです。
恐らくこのjsonキーから特定のテキストを抽出の上、opensslで変換かと思いますが、
どれだけググってもジャストフィットするQAがありませんでした。

やりたいことは以下リンク先の「CA証明書を取得します」の欄です。

[QTS で Azure SSO を設定する方法は？](https://www.qnap.com/ja-jp/how-to/tutorial/article/qts-%E3%81%A7-azure-sso-%E3%82%92%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AF)

なにかヒントになるご回答をいただければ、幸いです。